# VS.PHP Custom syntax coloring

Tags: visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I've just installed php plugin for visual studio 2010 (vs.php) and it seems a very good product, but I wonder if I can add a few more syntax coloring rules, as i find the default ones not enough for me. For example, i want to color php's predefined functions with a specified color and to make them bold. Also I want everything that is between the php tags  to have a blue background. Is that possible? To create own parsing rules or some kind of that?

Or maybe there is a way to create a plugin for visual studio to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2010 makes it easy to roll out your own extensions through Managed Extensibility Framework.

Here is a great [article](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/11/04/LearnVSXNowPart38.aspx) that explains how you can create your own extension for syntax highlighing. And some good [examples](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsxteam/archive/2009/06/17/new-editor-samples-for-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx).

However, keep in mind that syntax highlighting in VS is dependent on the language service provider's capabilities. E.g., in C#, there is no way to distinguish between a variable member of a class vs. a method of the class since VS identifies both of them as `Identifiers`.

I don't work on PHP so I cannot speak for whether there is a way to identify the pre-built functions or not through the language service provider. Something to keep in mind.

You may try this [trick](http://www.cumps.be/nl/blog/read/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring) useful too which basically fools VS into thinking `.php` files as `C++`

Lastly, you might know it already but this may be a good IDE: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do already read about Managed Extensibility Framework on MSDN, but your links helped me a lot. I thought maybe is possible to create a file with php's predefined functions and add a rule if matches bla bla...Anyway your answer was helpful, get the bounty!

Comment: Great to know that! Don't forget to upload your extension to codeplex so that next time someone can directly link to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could download a vssettings file with a custom syntax highlight, or you could edit yours as well by opening it in any text editor... in fact it is a xml file...

Comment: mulţămim de răspuns, însă: by vssettings file I can't add new syntax coloring rules, just edit the current ones. (what I actually can do in visual studio's settings, so that's not what i am looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking on VS menu? `Tools>Options>Environtment Fonts and Colors` I usually customize the looks of other type of documents there.

Comment: yes i did but that's not enough for me. I want to add more functionality, not just customize the current one.